# Xcode gives crash reports for TestFlight app… but how do I read it?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, app-store-connect, testflight

Xcode nicely gives these crash reports for apps on the App Store or TestFlight in the Organizer window, but how the heck do I read them? They don't seem to give any information as to what caused the crash, it just gives the line that they occurred on.

Even if I ask it to show me the error within my project, it just highlights the line in red and says "Thread 1", but I was expecting something like "nil value unexpectedly encountered" or something helpful.

Is there a way to get what caused the crash, not just what line? I'm looking at the line and have no clue as to what is crashing.

Answer (score 0):

You can desymbolize crash logs. I use Crashlytics to upload .dSYM files so later I can put crash log in good use.

You can read more about crash logs from Apple documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AnalyzingCrashReports/AnalyzingCrashReports.html

Comment: Apple doesn't automatically do that for their own crash service?

Comment: I saw that not all crashes Apple is catching. And I can follow if the latest release is stable better from Fabric.io dashboard.